# Is it possible to modify a pattern Validator to include removing blank spaces written in an input field?

Tags: regex, angular, requiredfieldvalidator, customvalidator

I have a validator running in which I check the format of the phone entered to be compatible with the information requested by the backend.
Would it be possible to modify this regex so that it removes or does not take into account if spaces are written between the numbers entered?
here my validator

```
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({

      mobilePhone: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          CustomValidators.patternValidator(/^((\+)33|0|0033)[1-9](\d{2}){4}$/, { onlyNumber: true })
        ]
      ],
...
```

Thank you in advance?

Comment: Just add `\s*` at the start, end and in between other subpatterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**REGEX:**

```
/^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/
```

You can create regex and test on regex101.com 
[Here i have done for mobile number validation](https://regex101.com/r/fX2bZ8/1)

**If Regex Doesn't work then you can create a service for mobile number validation like this :**

SERVICE File (validaion.service.ts)

```
import * as PhoneNumber from 'awesome-phonenumber';

 static mobileNumberValidator(control) {
    const mobile = new PhoneNumber.default(control.value, 'US');
    return (!mobile.isValid() || !mobile.isMobile()) ? { invalidMobile: false } : null;
  }
```

TS FILE

```
mobileNumber: ['', [Validators.required, 
Validators.maxLength(13), ValidationService.mobileNumberValidator]],
```

HTML

```
<p class="error" *ngIf="editProfileForm.get('mobileNumber').touched && yourformName['mobileNumber'].errors ">
<span class="error-message" 
*ngIf="!editProfile['mobileNumber'].errors.required && !editProfile.mobileNumber.errors.invalidMobile">
Cell phone number is not valid</span>
 </p>
```